# Full-screen 3x3 CSS Grid

Tags: css

I need a good example on how to create a full-screen 3x3 CSS grid.
The sourrounding tiles should have a fixed height/width, whereas the middle tile should have the rest of the screen width/height.

I have searched the web for examples, but haven't stumbled upon a good example yet.

Comment: What have you tried? Is there particular markup in place that you're trying to style? Please post some code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A 3x3 grid is easily done with display:table

```
<style type="text/css">
    html, body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .grid3x3 {
        display:table;
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
    }
    .grid3x3 > div {
        display:table-row;
        width:100%;
    }
    .grid3x3 > div:first-child,
    .grid3x3 > div:last-child {
        height: 100px;
    }
    .grid3x3 > div > div {
        display:table-cell;
    }
    .grid3x3 > div > div:first-child,
    .grid3x3 > div > div:last-child {
        width:100px;
    }

    div {
        outline: 1px solid orange;
    }

</style>
<div class="grid3x3">
    <div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>4</div>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>6</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>7</div>
        <div>8</div>
        <div>9</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The surrounding elements DO have a fixed width and height of 100px. (Obviously, the ones on in the middle sides cannot have a fixed height and the ones in the middle top and bottom cannot have a fixed width)